# ASP.NET: Format dynamically create controls

Tags: asp.net

I create controls for data input on the fly. It consist of set of (rows) labels and textboxes/comboboxes.

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = descTest;
Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" : "));
Panel1.Controls.Add(ddList);
```

Now the labels and textboxes of all the rows are not aligned. How can it be done? I need to rows & columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asp:Table` instead, it will make lot easier for you to format things in rows and columns:

aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="table" runat="server">
</asp:Table>
```

Code behind:

```
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.Text = descTest;

TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell2.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
row.Cells.Add(cell2);

table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: for formatting, you can use this table inside panel too or if you using panel to load controls then you can replace it with table...